# The import com.google cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using a tutorial at this page:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

It tells me to change the main activity, everything is going well except for this error:
"The import com.google cannot be resolved"

The line highlighted is:

```
import com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMessaging;
```

What could be the problem? Should it be my project name instead of com.google? Because I have a java file that is Web.SMS.C2DMessaging.

Comment: Do you have your c2dm library properly referenced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you add `c2dm.jar` to your project's build path?

[image]

First copy the `c2dm.jar` to `lib` folder in your project (create one if there are none).

1.) Right click on your project and select `Properties`.
2.) Select `Java Build Path` and select `Libraries` tab.
3.) Click `Add External JARs...` button and choose the `c2dm.jar` from `lib` folder.
4.) Click `Open` and `OK`.